# WordPress Homepage won't show new blog post in visitors

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, posts

I am facing a problem where new blog posts won't show up on the homepage of the site. The website is running with the latest PHP and in WordPress powered by Plesk in a VPS server.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Deactivate and even reinstall all plugins.
- Deactivate and even reinstall the theme (I also changed the theme with another).
- Clearing both WordPress's cache and CloudFlare's cache.
- Change CloudFlare to "Developer Mode" to make sure there's no problem with Cloudflare.
- Change cache plugin (currently, I have the WP Rocket, but also tried many others).
- Reinstall WordPress using the "WordPress reinstall" button in the "Updates" page.
- Changing PHP versions.
- Renaming the .htaccess file.
- Removed all files with cache in the /root/ folders.
- Trying visiting the website with "Private window" and also from different laptops, PCs, smartphones and IPs. Same.

I even put the website in the "under construction" page and it just won't show up. As an admin, I can see all the latest posts, but as a visitor, nothing really updates. For example, the Instagram widget won't show up the new images that I have uploaded, the slider doesn't work and nothing actually gets updated.

In the browser's console, I do see a few errors (as an admin I can't), and it's the same error for many plugins:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

This error goes to /wp-content/cache/busting/ and here's the link to the website that is facing the problems: https://artdecorationcrafting.gr/

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you analize the source code of your page, check for the .js files (like jquery which is like wp-core javascript) and try to open the link up you will end in what it feels like a 404 page and not the actual .js files. That is enough to break all your website if it is using some sort of frontend JS relying on jquery

Comment: Thank your for your reply Diego, much appreciated! I don't see any JS file giving me 404 page error. That happened after updating to the newer WordPress version, but even if I downgrade or install Enable jQuery Migrate Helper" won't fix the problem.

Comment: I just saw that if visiting a JS file as a visitor gives me an error: 
   
 try {
     console.log("- ERROR - Original site javascript does not exist. This is a placeholder.  Url is '

Comment: Just a few second ago when i tried i landed in a WP 404 page which was similar yo your site graphic style, so i guess i still was inside the site. Instead, if i visit it now i get exactly the message you pasted

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Mmm... if you ask me it is very weird that visiting an url of a phisical existing file gives that error. I would suggest to temporary disable cache (even Cloudflare) and try that again. If the file actually exist, it has not so many reason for not being displayed. Either it's a cache related problem or you have some firewall / .htaccess rules that are blocking something

Comment: Dear @Diego, fist things first: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it! I've fixed the problem and posted the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was CloudFlare and Ezoic. After changing the nameservers back the the main ones, fully removing CloudFlare and Ezoic, the blog started working again.